# How do I iterate and format my values in an object but also return it as an object?

Tags: javascript

so I have an object like so:

```
const maxValues = {
  flexMaxSeatYear: 16270,
  flexMaxTotalCost: 8879809,
  flexMaxTotalNPV: 7026931,
  tradMaxSeatYear: 12979,
  tradMaxTotalCost: 6684694,
  tradMaxTotalNPV: 5504844,
}
```

and I have a function to format these object values to strings and it will output something like this:

```
const maxValues = {
  flexMaxSeatYear: '16270',
  flexMaxTotalCost: '8879809',
  flexMaxTotalNPV: '7026931',
  tradMaxSeatYear: '12979',
  tradMaxTotalCost: '6684694',
  tradMaxTotalNPV: '5504844',
}
```

**What I've tried**

I can get these numbers formatted like this:

```
Object.values(maxValues).map(values => values.toLocaleString('en')
// ['16270', '8879809', '7026931' ....]
```

but that only returns an array of just the values. Is there a method out there that can help return the the object that have adjusted values but with the keys?  Thank you.

Comment: You're saying "I have an object" and "I have a function". What exactly are you actually looking for? Is the 2nd snippet the desired output or no? And why do you want to turn those numbers into strings in the first place? And what's the role of `toLocaleString()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get an object:

```js
const maxValues = {"flexMaxSeatYear":16270,"flexMaxTotalCost":8879809,"flexMaxTotalNPV":7026931,"tradMaxSeatYear":12979,"tradMaxTotalCost":6684694,"tradMaxTotalNPV":5504844};

const result = Object.entries(maxValues).reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({
  ...r,
  [k]: v.toLocaleString('en')
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map new objects and assign them to a single object.

```js
var maxValues = {
  flexMaxSeatYear: 16270,
  flexMaxTotalCost: 8879809,
  flexMaxTotalNPV: 7026931,
  tradMaxSeatYear: 12979,
  tradMaxTotalCost: 6684694,
  tradMaxTotalNPV: 5504844,
}

maxValues = Object.assign(
    ...Object
        .entries(maxValues)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v.toLocaleString('en') }))
);

console.log(maxValues);
```

Comment: Have you seen [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)? Still lousy support, but will work nicely with map.

Comment: Is there an advantage of doing it this way rather than just looping over the keys? It seems like this makes a lot of arrays in the process just to replace the original values.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, it takes the key/values in a single access. but you are right, it would be easier to have something to iterate an object and get a new object from this key/value pairs. actually it is one way of a functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the original, you could just loop over and mutate the `maxValues` object. This does not require creating an array of key value pairs like `Object.entries()` or other similar approaches, so it should be a bit faster for large datasets. However, this only matters if you don't need to preserve the original unmutated.

For example:

```js
const maxValues = {
  flexMaxSeatYear: 16270,
  flexMaxTotalCost: 8879809,
  flexMaxTotalNPV: 7026931,
  tradMaxSeatYear: 12979,
  tradMaxTotalCost: 6684694,
  tradMaxTotalNPV: 5504844,
};

for (const k in maxValues) {
  maxValues[k] = maxValues[k].toLocaleString();
}

console.log(maxValues);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like they are looking for the output `toLocaleString` delivers. `toString()` is probably better here.

Comment: Not a single statement, but a million times more readable than the accepted answer.